# Как разделить число на цифры?

Tags: c++

Например, дано число 123456789, нужно разделить его на отдельные цифры, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, чтобы их потом можно было бы присвоить к какой-то переменной. И как называется сам этот процесс, чтобы поподробнее прочитать про эту функцию потом.

Comment: На Питоне: `digits = map(int, str(n))` или `digits = lambda n, result=[]: digits(n//10, [n%10] + result) if n else result or [0]`
 См. [Как разложить двузначное число на два однозначных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516165/23044)

Answer (score 21):

Легкий путь

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main ()
{
  int num = 12345678,
  idig = 5;
  char digs[20];

  sprintf(digs, "%d", num);
  if (strlen(digs) > idig)
    printf ("%d-th digit in %d is '%c'\n", idig, num, digs[idig - 1]);
  else
    printf ("there is no %d-th digit in %d\n", idig, num);
}
```

---

> Если честно, то мне трудно понять смысл этих строчек:
>
> ```
> sprintf(digs,"%d",num);
> if (strlen(digs) > idig)
>     printf ("%d-th digit in %d is '%c'\n", idig, num, digs[idig - 1]);
> else
>     printf ("there is no %d-th digit in %d\n", idig, num);
> ```
>
> Вот тут я запутываюсь, а точнее в форматах (`%`).

Кратко описываю непонятные Вам места с форматами. Подробно можно прочитать в [man 3 fprintf](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fprintf&category=3).

Функции семейства *printf* (`sprintf()`, `fprintf()` и другие) выводят значение своих аргументов в виде последовательности символов в соответствии с форматами, передаваемыми аргументом функции в виде строки. `printf()` выводит символы в `stdout`, `fprintf()` — в указанный `FILE *`, а `sprintf()` — в строку (массив `char`) в вашей программе.

Текст строки форматов можно разделить на собственно форматы, «управляющие» (Control) и просто символы.

- Просто символы копируются на выход «как есть».
- Control символы управляют выводом текста на терминал (NewLine, Tab и пр.), их записывают в форматах, начиная символом «бэкслеш» («\»). Например: `\n` — Newline, `\t` — табуляция, `\g` — bell (терминал пищит). Также (это по правилам записи строковых констант в С) надо писать `\"` для вывода кавычки. Если надо вывести сам символ «\», то его надо удвоить: `\\`.
- Символ «%» в строке форматов имеет особое значение. Он начинает очередной формат, который говорит, в каком виде должен быть выведен следующий аргумент и какого он типа. Например:

  - `%d` — вывести аргумент типа `int` в виде десятичного числа,
  - `%c` — вывести аргумент типа `char` (или младший байт `int`) как символ (то есть без преобразований),
  - `%x` — вывести аргумент типа `int` в виде шестнадцатеричного числа

    и так далее. Форматов много, они удобны. Прочтите *man* и пользуйтесь.

Возвращаясь к указанным Вами непонятным местам в программе:

- `sprintf(digs, "%d", num);` сформирует в массиве `digs` последовательность цифр числа и переменной `num` в соответствии с форматом `%d` (то есть выводит в строку число в десятичном виде);
- `if (strlen(digs) > idig)` проверяет, есть ли вообще цифра номер `idig`. Например Вы хотите вывести шестую цифру числа, а в числе (например 3) цифра всего одна.
- `printf ("%d-th digit in %d is '%c'\n", idig, num, digs[idig - 1]);` вывести в stdout:

  - первый `%d` — переменную `idig` (номер цифры в числе) как десятичное число,
  - второй `%d` — переменную `num` как десятичное число,
  - `%c` — символ из массива `digs` (искомую цифру) «как есть».

Надеюсь, теперь стало понятнее. А вообще, читайте, читайте и еще раз читайте документацию.

Comment: Извиняюсь, а этот код не для Си разве??? 

А на счет книжки, то скажу так. Я обычно стараюсь решать заданную мне задачу. Для этого ищу материал если не знаю как сделать, по ходу решения это все. Т.е рассматриваю конкретные случаи с которыми сталкиваюсь.
 Я поэтому написал, что как вот называется так скажем этот процесс или метод, чтобы найти в книге эту тему и изучать подробно.

Comment: Код на C. C++ компилятор его тоже прекрасно воспринимает, не волнуйтесь. Если Вам нравится cout << tram_ham_pam << ... и в этом для Вас C++, то напишите с cout. 

Вы просили простой и понятный код. IMHO понятней некуда (конечно надо понимать, что символ (char) это 8-разрядное число в котором хранится **ASCII код** десятичной цифры). Кстати, для перевода десятичной цифры (из символа) в число (int) просто вычтите из этого символа символ '0'.

Книжку Вам советую просто внимательно прочесть от начала до конца, а потом (уже при втором прочтении) начинать писать программы.

Comment: @avp, при всем уважении, это решение - халтура.

Comment: Почему ? Человек хочет цифры. Пусть берет их из char \*. Не понимаю, чем плохо ? Обязательно нуженн массив int ?

 Можно пробежать по строке и сделать (в комментарии показал ему как). 

@mikillskegg, Вы рекурсию ему специально подкинули ? Он IMHO в циклах путается.

Про KISS - принцип наверное слышали ?

Comment: @avp, согласитесь, он ничему не научится, если все будет упрощать до неузнаваемости.

Comment: @Dex, он уже получил здесь 3 ответа одного типа. Пусть увидит еще один подход (не математический).

Кстати, насчет халтуры. Да, сплоховал. Если число отрицательное, то надо его вначале на -1 умножить.

Comment: Такой подход и быстрее, и очевиднее, чем остатки от деления в рекурсии. Я за этот ответ, хотя они все верны.

Comment: Для многих очевидней, но не быстрее, а очевидно медленнее (и памяти сожрет больше). 

Функция sprintf() достаточно сложная, выполняет много действий, а где-то в глубине себя получает цифры именно остатками от деления на 10.

--

Просто глядя на этот пример, нетрудно догадаться, как надо использовать замечательную функцию из ответа @northerner.

Comment: Можно совсем выпендриться и применить boost::lexical_cast (кстати, очень удобная штука).

Comment: а этот код кто.может для с++ написать? Если не трудно. Я не.могу.понять некоторые вещи на си =/

Comment: если честно, то мне трудно понять смысл этих строчек:

  sprintf(digs,"%d",num);
  if (strlen(digs) > idig)
    printf ("%d-th digit in %d is '%c'\n",idig,num,digs[idig-1]);
  else
    printf ("there is no %d-th digit in %d\n",idig,num);

Вот тут я запутываюсь, а точнее в форматах (%)

Comment: спасибо большое! Читаю! Вот уже начал с Дейтел (5-ое Малое Издание). А на счет изменения, это не я меняю, а какой то Angry Bird взял и изменил, но он изменил только правописание, так скажем, смысл одинаковый! Спасибо еще раз за труд!

Comment: @avp, перенесите, пожалуйста абзац, начинающийся с `у меня закончился лимит комментариев, поэтому отвечаю здесь` сюда, в комментарии. Текст можно взять из истории.

Comment: @Arhad, понятия не имею, как это делать (да и стоит ли тратить усилия на совсем старые ленты комментариев?).

Comment: @avp, вообще можно просто скопировать текст и добавить комментарий обычным порядком, но да, смысл действительно сомнителен.

Comment: @Arhad, вот и мне кажется, что вряд ли хоть кому-то будет от тех комментариев польза или удовольствие.

Answer (score 17):

Или так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void parse (int n, vector<int>& vec) {
    vec.push_back (n%10);
    int temp = n / 10;  
    if (temp == 0 ) return;
    parse (temp, vec);
}

int main() {
    int n = 4500345;
    vector <int> vec;
    parse (n, vec);
    copy (vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), ostream_iterator <int> (cout, "   "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: понимаете, неужели для этой задачи нет легкого пути? Вот в вашем щас коде, очень много новизны для новичка, очень. Новые библиотеки и т.д. А нельзя ли попроще решить его? Решение для новичка, скажем так.

Comment: Тут главное - понять, как определить, в каком разряде какая цифра. Одно из самых изящных решений - рекурсия, что я и продемонстрировал.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Раскладывает целое число в массив цифр
 *
 * Функция factor_digits извлекает цифры числа и размещает в заданном
 * массиве в обратной последовательности, в соответствии с нумерацией
 * разрядов, то есть элемент массива с индексом нуль получит значение
 * нулевого разряда (крайней правой цифры) и т.д. В случае, если при
 * разложении достигнуто заданное третьим параметром максимальное
 * количество цифр, функция прекращает работу, возвращая нуль, в
 * противном случае возвращает количество цифр в разложении.
 *
 * @param num    Число для разложения
 * @param digits Массив для размещения результата разложения
 * @param limit  Максимально допустимое количество цифр  
 * @returns      количество полученных цифр в разложении,
 *               0, если превышено предельное количество цифр
 */
int factor_digits(int num, int *digits, int limit)
{
    int digits_count = 0;

    // Отдельно обрабатываем ситуацию, когда число изначально равно нулю
    if (num == 0) {
        digits[0] = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    // Последовательно извлекаем цифры числа, пока они есть
    while (num > 0 && limit) {
        // Копируем очередную цифру в массив
        digits[digits_count++] = num % 10;
        // Переходим к следующей цифре
        num /= 10;
        // Уменьшаем допустимое количество оставшихся цифр
        limit--;
   }
   return num ? 0 : digits_count;
}

/**
 * Тестовая программа, демонстрирующая разложение числа на цифры
 */
int main()
{
    int n = 123456789;          // Разложим для примера число 123456789 
    int factored_number[10];    // Массив для хранения результата
    int factored_number_len;    // Количество цифр в числе
    int i;

    // Выполняем разложение
    factored_number_len = factor_digits(n, factored_number, 10);

    // Выводим результат на экран
    for (i = factored_number_len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d\n", factored_number[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) cout что вывести, num?
2) что означает "/="?

Comment: Реверс массива digits[] добавить и почти совсем хорошо. 

Кстати, неплхо бы отрицательные числа тоже обрабатывать (ведь цифры в них такие же, как и в положительных).

Comment: ответьте пожалуйста, а в итоге что вывести должен? Можете и это дополнить в ответ?

Comment: 0) Добавил тестовую программу. Так как начал писать на чистом C, не стал использовать конструкций C++ вообще. Разумеется, компилятор C++ этот код поймет.<br>
1) Результат разложения (цифры числа) функция записывает по указателю digits. Передаете массив в качестве второго параметра, получаете разложение. В качестве третьего параметра передавайте количество элементов массива (на работу алгоритма этот параметр не влияет, служит лишь защитой от потенциального переполнения буфера).
2) Выражение x /= 10 эквивалентно выражению x = x / 10.

Comment: 3) Разворачивать массив специально не стал - так удобнее использовать в задачах длинной арифметики (числа оказываются автоматически выровнены по правому краю).
4) По поводу отрицательных чисел согласен. Для этого можно в цикле заменить условие (num > 0) на (num != 0) и при копировании цифры в массив брать модуль остатка.

Comment: а вот что на.счет использования цикла while скажете? Ну он будет делить на 10 и брать остаток?и вывести их, точнее записать в массив. В коде я прост запутываюсь, нужна помлщь

Comment: @navi1893. Все на самом деле просто. 

Остаток от деления дает **последнюю** цифру. **Целочисленное** деление - удаляет ее из числа (другими словами сдвигает число вправо так, что **последняя** цифра исчезает). 

Вся эта процедура повторяется, пока в числе **еще есть цифры**.

Comment: Спасибо. А как добавить потом эти числа в массив?

Comment: Эта строка кода (в программе есть комментарий !!!)

    digits[digits_count++] = num % 10;

помещает цифры числа в массив, который Вы передаете как параметр при вызове функции factor_digits(n, factored_number, 10);

Comment: @avp, я бы сказал не **последнюю цифру**, а **самый младший разряд**. По определению, остаток < делителя. При том, что делитель у нас - основание системы счисления, вуаля, получили цифру. Сполоснуть и повторить пока исходное число > 0

Answer (score 12):

```
int i = 1234567890;
string nums;
stringstream ss;
ss << i;
ss >> nums;
int* numbers = new int[nums.length()];
for(int j = 0; j < nums.length(); j++) {
    stringstream s;
    s << nums.c_str()[j];
    s >> numbers[j];
}
```

Comment: Извините за красоту, с телефона сижу:))

Answer (score 8):

```
void outputdigits(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return;

   int d = n % 10;

   outputdigits(n / 10);

   cout << d << " "; 
}
```

Comment: а как он(этот процесс) называется? хочу про него подробно изучить

Comment: @navi1893, рекурсия? `%` - взятие остатка от деления?

Comment: У меня просто вот задача, дано число N. Надо найти например ее 6-ую цифру и вывести. Что подскажете мне?

Comment: Если вам дан конкретный номер цифры (разряда), которую надо найти, а все разложение не требуется тогда все гораздо проще - достаточно разделить это число на 10 в степени номер разряда и взять остаток от деления на 10 (разряды нумеруются с нуля справа налево). Например, дано число 1234, нужны сотни - цифра в разряде номер 2. Делим 1234 на 10^2 - получаем 12, берем остаток от деления 12 на 10 - получаем 2.

Comment: Не верно же, эта формула не для.всех пройдет, например 12345 найти 4. Не выйдет

Comment: @navi1893 Конечно же выйдет, на втором проходе как раз получите 4. Но такой подход не очень удобен, т.к. для доступа к одной цифре нужно сначала высчитать все... Ну или все до нужной, если чуть упростить.

Answer (score 3):

Функция которая получает в первом параметре число из которого нужно получить определенную цифру и второй параметр какую именно цифру из числа надо получить. Возвращает нужную вам цифру. Цифру которую нужно получить отсчитывает с конца числа.

```
/*
    1234567890     = число
      ^------- 8   = цифра которая нужна
 */
int func(int chislo, size_t offset)
{
    char str_chislo[20];
    sprintf(str_chislo, "%d", chislo);

    // Если нужная цифра больше чем цифр в числе возвращает -1
    if (offset > strlen(str_chislo)) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < offset; i++) {
        chislo /= 10;
    }

    return chislo % 10;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", func(1234567890, 8)); // Вывод будет 3
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double res;
    int a;
    cout<<"Input a"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    res=0;
    do
    {
        res=(res+a%10)*10; 
        a=a/10;
        if (a<10) res=res+a;
    }
    while (a>10);
    cout<<res<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте пояснения к коду

Answer (score 2):

Простейшая программа на Си раскладывающая любое число long на цифры.

```
void digit(long n)
{
    int k;

    while (n != 0) 
    {
        k = n % 10;
        printf("%i,", k);
        n /= 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А если просто конвертировать в `std::string`?

```
std::vector<int> func(int number)
{
    std::vector<int> output;
    for(auto oneChar: std::to_string(number))
        output.push_back(int(oneChar - '0'));

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ну хз мб кому то поможет

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    cout << "ведите число " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    b = a/10;
    c = a % 10;
    cout << "первый  цифр " << b << endl;
    cout << "второй  цифр " << c << endl;
    _getch();
}

//и так например  a=5846
int a, b, c, d, e, r, t;
b = a/1000;  //5
c = a%1000;
d = c / 100; //8
e = c % 100;
r = e / 10; //4
t = e % 10; //6
```

как легче я не знаю)))). это к стати моя домашняя робота .

п.с если число х не определенно(те есть ты не знаешь сколько цифр будет) то я не знаю

Comment: ужас то какой!!!

Comment: лол да придётся видимо ещё був что бы сработало шас поправлю

Comment: Это может кому-то помочь только получить очередную двойку по программированию)

Comment: да всё робит теперь я просто на 2 цифра проверил а а тут 4 надо их по очереди так сказать урезать с %

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int number;
cout << "enter number "; cin >> number;
while (number > 0) {
    cout << number % 10 << "\n"; //последная цифра
    number = number / 10;
}
return 0;
}
```

Не зависемо от размера числа
Сначала вводим число после чего программа берет последную цифру, после чего просто уберает последую цифру и повтарает.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -3):

```
cin >> i;
string s = static_cast<string> i;//ну или по другому преобразуйте. точно не помню
cout << s[num];
```

Comment: А ты пробовал такой код компилировать?

Comment: да. у меня работал

Comment: Вы не перепутали с `boost::lexical_cast`?