# Как разложить двузначное число на два однозначных

Tags: python, python-2.x

Например 43 на 4 и 3. В стандартной библиотеке ничего подходящего не нахожу или плохо знаю математику. Кроме костылей, типа перевести число в строку и разбить, ничего путного в голову не приходит.

Comment: остаток и частное от целочисленного деления на 10

Comment: divmod же, точно, спассибо!

Comment: @splash58 ваш комментарий должен быть ответом

Comment: @PavelMayorov может быть, вы и правы, но я могу в ответе написать одну эту фразу - про питон я знаю только название :)

Comment: А этого вполне достаточно для ответа. Не обязательно же "портянку" на 200 строк разводить :)

Comment: краткость - сестра таланта :))

Comment: Был бы вопрос по Javascript - обязательно бы посоветовал использовать jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

то, что вы хотите получить - это остаток и частное от целочисленного деления на 10

Answer (score 6):

Для двухзначного числа достаточно
[`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod)
вызывать:

```
>>> divmod(43, 10)
(4, 3)
```

В общем случае, ничего плохого нет в том чтобы в строку преобразовать:

```
>>> " + ".join(str(123))
'1 + 2 + 3' # сумма цифр (выражение)
```

Если нужно, чтобы отдельные цифры имели тип `int`, то достаточно
`map()` вызвать:

```
>>> sum(map(int, str(123)))
6  # сумма цифр (результат)
```

Вариант `digits = str(number)` является читаемым и, не измеряя
скорость, я бы не стал предполагать, что работает быстрее для разных
входных диапазонов: вариант с `map(int, str(number))` или вариант,
который явное деление на 10 (основание системы счисления) использует:

```
def digits(n, result=[]):
    return digits(n//10, [n%10] + result) if n else result or [0]
```

или код с явным циклом:

```
def digits(n):
    result = []
    while n:
        n, digit = divmod(n, 10)
        result.append(digit)
    result.reverse()
    return result or [0]
```

Пример:

```
>>> digits(123)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Для больших `n` (миллионы цифр) последний вариант мог бы быть более
предпочтительным, так как
[`str(long)` в СPython является квадратичной операцией](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279),
а представленная реализация с явным циклом имела бы линейную сложность, если бы `n, digit = divmod(n, 10)` за постоянное время выполнялся.

Answer (score 2):

```
def ttt(n):
    l = []
    while (n > 0):
        l.insert(0, n%10)
        n = n/10
    return l

print ttt(15896)
```

Для 3-его придется править. ИМХО, через строку - проще.

П.С. - только для положительных чисел))

Comment: Достаточно в функции заменить `n = n / 10` на `n = n // 10`, и она будет одинаково работать на Python2 и Python3.

Comment: Спасибо, но splash уже ответил.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю такое число может состоять не только из двух цифр. Незнаю как в `python`, но в `php` я бы делал так: перевел в строку и обращался по номеру символа. Что-то вроде такого:

```
<?php
$number = 46;
$numberStr = (string) $number;
echo $numberStr[0];
```