# Определение цифры в числе python

Tags: python

Нужно вытащить первую и последнюю цифру из любого трехзначного числа на Python. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49244/discussion-on-question-by-s3mpau-----python).

Comment: как это запихнуть в цикл с 6знач числами чтобы узнало все цифры

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как разложить двузначное число на два однозначных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516165/23044) (с [общим решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506519/23044))

Comment: @AmirBanov: если хотите новый вопрос задать, то [нажмите "Задать вопрос" кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Комментарии не предназначены для новых вопросов.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм решения задачи может выглядеть так:

1. Сконвертировать число в строку.
2. Получить первый символ строки и преобразовать его в число.
3. Получить последний символ строки и преобразовать его в число.

В коде это может выглядеть так:

```
num = 123
s = str(num)

# Первая цифра
first_digit = int(s[0])
# Последняя цифра
last_digit = int(s[-1])
```

Comment: Как написать условия сравнения? Я просто школьник :D

Comment: Это не может служить оправданием нежелания учится. На ваш основной, конкретный, вопрос я ответил. Если есть другие вопросы - задайте их отдельно.

Answer (score 3):

Альтернативный алгоритм без приведения к строке:

```
value = 123

first_digit = value // 100
second_digit = value % 10
```