# GNU C++ 4.8.4,перевод из int в char mass[]

Tags: c++

Имеется массив `mass[]` и число `int q`. Необходимо записать q по разрядам в массив.

Компилятор выдает ошибку `was not declared in this scope` при использовании `_itoa_s` и `sprintf`. Библиотеки подключены. Какие ещё существуют способы разложения числа на разряды и записи в массив символов?

Пример кода не нужен, т.к. код исправно работает в VS 2015, как с `itoa`, так и с `sprintf`. Нужна альтернатива этим функциям, можно даже самописную.

Comment: [mcve] в студию!

Comment: где сам код???  мы тут не телепаты? приведите пример кода, в котором ошибка.

Comment: @Alex.B, смотрите в [очереди правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/142875). Вопрошающий незарегистрирован, а потому предложил анонимную правку, потеряв доступ к исходной учётной записи.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89649/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: Деление (и взятие остатка). Только внимательней с `INT_MIN`...

Comment: Функций `itoa` или `_itoa_s`  в стандартной билиотеке не существует и никогда не сущестовало. Про проблемы со `sprintf` - это ваши выдумки. Никаких проблем с использовнаием `sprintf` в GCC нет.

Answer (score 3):

Итак, тэг C++, альтернатива...

Функция [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) устроит? C последующим копированием в массив, если уж так нужно?

Или надо **только** самописный вариант?